# Timeout Configuration

Tags: mule

I am configuring transaction and response timeout for API in Mule 4, Is there anyway that I set different timeout for different methods(GET,POST,DELETE) for single API in Mule Soft because the API has different SLA for different operations ?

Answer (score 0):

As the http timeout is set at the connector level that does not allow you to set timeouts per method.

One way you could try to achieve this is via separating your interface flow from your logic. Then have your interface flow call your logic flow via something like vm where you can set a timeout individually. You can then catch the timeout error and do what you want with it.

Here is an example that has a flow for a POST method. All this flow does is offload the logic to another floe and invokes that logic using v:publish-consume and awaits the response. It sets a timeout of 2 seconds(configurable with properties etc.) and catches `VM:QUEUE-TIMEOUT` errors and sets an 'SLA exceeded'error message:

```
     <flow name="myPOSTInterface">
        <vm:publish-consume queueName="postQueue" config-ref="vm" timeout="2" timeoutUnit="SECONDS" />

        <logger level="INFO" message="Result from logic flow: #[payload]" />

        <error-handler>
            <on-error-continue type="VM:QUEUE_TIMEOUT">
                <set-payload value="#[{error: 'SLA exceeded'}]" />
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </flow>

    <flow name="myPOSTLogic">
        <vm:listener config-ref="vm" queueName="postQueue" />
        <set-payload value="#[{result: 'Result from my logic'}]" />
    </flow>
```